# I am having problem while fetching data. How do I fetch data like this?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

```
{
"type": "champion",
"format": "standAloneComplex",
"version": "12.23.1",
"data": {
"Aatrox": {
"version": "12.23.1",
"id": "Aatrox",
"key": "266",
"name": "Aatrox"}
```

This is what I am trying to fetch. (This goes on with some more heroes.)

```
const Heroes = () =\> {
const [champions, setChampions\] = useState([]);

useEffect(() =\> {
const getHeroes = async () =\> {
try {
const res = await fetch(
"https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.23.1/data/en_US/champion.json"
);
const data = await res.json();
setChampions(data.data)

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getHeroes();

}, []);
return <div>
{champions.map((champion)=>(
<p>{champion.name}</p>
))}
```

;
};

I tried fetching like this, but I am getting an error. I don't know what to do, and I would be happy if someone could help.

Comment: The error message would be helpful.

Comment: TypeError: champions.map is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You get an object from the API, not an array. So you cannot use `.map()` on `champions`. Once the data is fetched, you need to convert the object to an array before updating the state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getHeroes = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.23.1/data...");
      const data = await res.json();
      const heroesArray = Object.values(data.data); // convert the object to an array
      setChampions(heroesArray);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  getHeroes();
}, []);
```

Working Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-butterfly-9r2ofz?file=/src/App.js